# Continuous Integration with Jenkins: Binary Output need to be copied to a shared directory

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Our .NET app with 8-10 projects and created a Jenkins job to build it.
We also have a batch job called in Jenkins to create the set up files for our app using INNO Setup. The issue we need to address is copy the Setup files to a shared location. Could you please suggest a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: I think I understand your use case, but I just want to be clear.  What you want to do looks like this:  build a project  --> create "setup program" for the built project --> copy the "setup program" to a shared location.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. And to add a point I am done with step 1 and step 2.

Step 1: Build the visual studio project using MSBuild

Step 2: Execute windows batch command.

The batch command uses the innox compiler to create the set up files in the specified output directory. 

Should I do an x-copy of the set up files from batch command to a specified shared location? Is this the correct way to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you will probably want to use a publishing plugin.  There are different plugins depending on where (and how) you want to put the file.  Here's a quick list to get you started:

- [Publish Over FTP Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin)  - use if you want to send the output to an FTP location
- [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)  - use if you want to use SSH to publish your artifacts.
- [Publish Over CIFS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin)  - use this if you are wanting to put stuff in a Windows (CIFS , SMB) share

A larger list can be found in the [Artifact Uploader Plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Artifactuploaders) list.

Answer (score 3):

In a .NET environment you should have a look at Nant (http://nant.sourceforge.net/).

Use a Nant script as a post-build action with a default.build like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="MyProject" default="network-copy" basedir=".">
    <target name="network-copy">
        <copy file="target\setup.exe"
            todir="\\server\share$\directory"></copy>
    </target>
</project>
```